# End points for services module not working

Tags: services

I have setup an endpoint following [this guide](https://drupal.org/comment/reply/1699354). I am getting mixed results, as **endpoint/node.xml** successfully returns a list of content nodes.

When I try and load an individual node as xml, I just get a blank xml document example below, clicking **/endpoint/node/1000.xml** results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result></result>
```

Also if I try and load it as a ...node/1000.json it just returns false.

Error log is really vague, content is open to non-authenticated users so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: What is your content with nid=1000?

Comment: http://localhost/d7/testendpoint/node/20.xml as well as http://localhost/d7/testendpoint/node/20.json both works for me, Make sure user has access to view nodes..

Comment: I am able to open the node normally /node/1000, I have removed the access permissions module, ensured published content is visible. Its really confusing as it can load the list of nodes but doesn't load specific nodes as xml.

Comment: @joe the content is a really basic content type, its just a body and an text field.

Comment: but the actual node with nid=1000 exists, right? what nids appear in the list at node.xml?

Comment: @joe The node exists and is also listed in the node.xml results.

Comment: Make the end point return some text, like 'abracadabra' hardcoded, just to make sure, you are declaring the end point right. If you are messing with arguments, sometimes it's easier to declare a different end point for a different use case than fight with arguments.

Comment: Found a work around, thank you for trying. Really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around for this issue, rather than use the node id I am using the UUID. This is now successfully loading the content.

The UUID id is pulled out of the main list of nodes at **/endpoint/node.xml**, giving a working url of:

**/endpoint/node/e2349095-de4f-4827-919f-3ec28cf392a8**